# Software to change non responsive website to a responsive website

Tags: html, static, responsive, web-development-server

I a beginner in Web Development. I've just made a website which is quite a basic one. But as I am a beginner so, that means that I've only made the website look alright. That means it is not responsive. When I change the browser dimensions, my website looks a mess.

I thought to myself, could there be a software or an app where I would upload my website and click change to responsive and my website would automatically change to responsive website. So, my question is, is there any software that could change my website to responsive? Here is a picture to my website.

[image]

Comment: In one word: yes! - Notepad.

Comment: @Turnip, Notepad? How would that work?

Comment: @Rafique By you typing the correct HTML and CSS code which makes your site responsive…

Comment: Well I know that @deceze but I thought maybe there could be some thing which could correct the coding for you and make your website responsive. Thanks any way..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did the css by yourself you should use media queries.

It allows you to condition your css depending on the screen size.

For exemple if you add this code at the end of your css file, the background of the body will be green if the screen is less than 1000 pixels wide :

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  body {
    background-color : green;
  }
}
```

But if you are a beginner in responsive design you should use the bootstrap framework : http://getbootstrap.com/ and read the doc, it's the perfect introduction for responsive design. (you can maybe tweak your site with bootstrap classes to make it responsive, although this is not a good way to do it, you have to think about it before ;) )

Have fun. (sorry for my english :p)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). They also have a couple of free basic templates.